# How to make responsive binding controls in universal windows app?

Tags: win-universal-app

I have this code in XAML:

```
<Image Height="120" x:Name="postPic" Width="120" Source="{x:Bind Thumb}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

How can i use setter to change width or height of image?

Comment: What do you want  do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Style.Setters`, Bind Width to a property or `VisualState.Setters` to change the size of the image.

In this case I think you can go with `AdaptiveTrigger` and `VisualState` to make responsive UI.